# "Controller method not found." Laravel error. How can I figure out what method was called that it couldn't find?

Tags: apache, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I started using Laravel a month ago. Trying to make a page with one form on it and I keep getting a "Controller method not found." error. There is only one form on the page and that method is being called fine and making the query that I want. It does redirect to the same page with that form, /dashboard/edit/module.

It would be awesome if I could see what method is not being found or where it is in my code. Any ideas how I can do this? Someone mentioned App::error or messing with Log::error in global.php but I can't get any more information shown.

Edit:

I found that the form action is only being found if I upload a video to the form. Other then that it gives me the same error. Here is the controller method of this form. The page with this form is /dashboard/edit/module and I would like to reload that page after this runs.

```
public function postSection(){

    $path = public_path() . "/videos/";

    $filename = uniqid() . '.mp4';

    $file_path = $path . $filename;

    $moduleID = Input::get('moduleID');

    if(!Input::hasFile('video')){

        return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'Must enter a valid video file.');

    }else{

        try {

            Input::file('video')->move($path, $filename);

            $section = New Section;

            $section->module_id = $moduleID;
            $section->video = $file_path;
            $section->save();

            //I was trying to use this instead of View::make to stop form resubmission
            //return Redirect::to('/dashboard/edit/module')->with('moduleID', $moduleID);

            return View::make('forms.editMod')->with('moduleID', $moduleID);

        }catch ( Exception $e){

            return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'Unable to save the video file.');

        }
    }

}
```

Edit: And my routes.php

```
    //Route for the home page
    Route::get('/', function(){ return View::make('home'); });

    //Controllers
    Route::controller('dashboard/edit', "ContentController");

    Route::controller('user', "UserController");

    Route::group(array('before'=> 'auth|dash'), function(){

    //dashboard home
    Route::get('/dashboard', function(){ return View::make('dashboard');});

    //dashboard subs
    Route::get('dashboard/modules', function(){ return View::make('forms.module');});
    Route::get('dashboard/users', function(){ return View::make('users');});
    Route::get('dashboard/reporting', function(){ return View::make('reporting');});


    //user pages
    Route::get('dashboard/register', function(){ return View::make('forms.register');});
    Route::post('dashboard/edit/user', array('before'=>'csrfajax', function(){

        $id = Input::get('userID');

        $user = User::find($id);

        return View::make('forms.editUser')->with('user', $user);
    }));
});
```

And the form...

```
{{ Form::open(array('files' => true, 'action' => 'ContentController@postSection', 'id' => 'sectionform')) }}
        <fieldset>
            {{ Form::label('Video (mp4)') }}
            {{ Form::hidden('moduleID', $module->id)}}
            {{ Form::file('video', array('id' => 'video', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}<br>
            {{ Form::submit('Save') }}
        </fieldset>
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `routes.php`, to reach this method you're using `Route::controller`, which results in RESTful routing.  If the browser's HTTP request used the POST action, you'd correctly be routed to `public function postSection(){}`.  But if the HTTP request used GET, which is the default for web browsing, especially when no data is being submitted by the browser, Laravel would be looking for a method called `public function getSection(){}`.  This would explain why when you're uploading something (i.e. using POST), you reach the page, but otherwise you don't.

See the official documentation for the full low-down on implicit routing: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#implicit-controllers